# Why does the type ( () => string ) appear out of nowhere?

Tags: typescript

I'm working with the *jasonwebtoken* package. I came across this new javascript/typescript behaviour.

```
interface JwtPayload {
    [key: string]: any;
    iss?: string | undefined;
    sub?: string | undefined;
    aud?: string | string[] | undefined;
    exp?: number | undefined;
    nbf?: number | undefined;
    iat?: number | undefined;
    jti?: string | undefined;
}
let payload: JwtPayload | string
let id: string | undefined

id = payload.sub
```

At the assignment I get the error. What is going on?

```
Type 'string | (() => string) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgFIHcwAU4E8A2A9nACbIDeAUMjcgNoDWEuAXMgM5hSgDmAumzghcAbmq1g7dgH42nbiB7IAPsgCuIEhBigIJMbQ5qARrI5deK9Zu2794mnDUkz8y6reK6fKxq06QPQNaCAAPAAczEDUAW2NoXxsAoIdkEGMYKNj4qET-O2CaYDgwLLiE1T9bQPtDACswYFcLRTzqlIBfSnwIMGRwvCJSNgxsQeIyDxaebt7kYBI5abbkkkpKBeQAXn7x0gA6dhMgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `payload` as either a `JwtPayload` *or* a string:

```
let payload: JwtPayload | string
```

That means `payload.sub` can either mean the `sub` property of `JwtPayload` *or* the `sub` property of `string`.

Turns out `sub` on a string exists: it's the [`String.prototype.sub()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/sub) method, which has the type `() => string`. So it doesn't come from nowhere.

To assign `payload.sub` to `id`, you'll need to make sure `payload` is not a string:

```
if (typeof payload !== 'string') {
    id = payload.sub;
}
```

That way the compiler can safely determine that it is a `JwtPayload`, which means `payload.sub` has the type you want.

You can also just assert that `payload` has the type you assume it has, but that just means telling the compiler to shut up about type safety, which means you'll need to cross your fingers it won't give out an error at runtime.